# Understanding XHR request object in javascript... (confused)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm following a simple book and It says:

```
function createRequest() 
{ 
    try 
    {  
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    catch (tryMS) 
    {  
        try 
        {   
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");  
        } 
        catch (otherMS) 
        {   
        try 
        {    
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
        } 
        catch (failed) 
        {    
            request = null;   
        }   
        }
    } 
 return request; 
 } 

function getDetails(itemName) 
{ 
    var request = createRequest();
    if (request==null) 
    {    alert("Unable to create request");  
        return;  
    } 
    var url= "getDetails.php?ImageID=" +    escape(itemName); 
    request.open("GET",url,true);  
    request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails; 
    request.send(null); 
}


function displayDetails() 
{  
    if (request.readyState == 4) 
    {    
        if (request.status == 200) 
        {      
            detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");      
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;    
        }  
    } 
}
```

And all this code above is fine and it's okay to me.. but after few pages it says:

**ITS VERY IMPORTANT TO REMOVE VAR KEYWORD BEFORE request VARIABLE so the callback can reference the variable...**

but how come in example above it worked? is it coincidence if we call a variable `'request'` that it will map with global variable in a `createRequest` method?

Take a look on image below:

[image]

Why is this happening ? in one example `var` before `request` variable is used and everything is fine, in another `var` is avoided so the method in callback might access it.. but how come method in a callback is accessing a `request` variable in first example...

It's confusing because there are 2 similar examples, with different explanations..

EDIT
P.S it says request has to be a global ? :o

[image]

Thanks guys
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples, implicit global variables are created so they can be shared with the callback.
When the second request variable is created, it creates a local variable inside the getDetails function. So when createRequest() returns the global variable, the local variable becomes a reference to it.

This is rather bad advice and shows a lack of understanding on the writers' part. But it seems to be an old text, since activeX objects are deprecated by now, so maybe globals used to be less frowned upon. The proper way is to either send the responseText or responseXML as a parameter to the callback or send the entire request as the parameter for the callback.

Maybe the writer didn't want to make the request code more complex, but imho, this is not a good way to teach people things.

```
function createRequest( method, url, callback, payload ) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ( !request ) {
        alert( "Unable to create request" );  
        return null;
    }
    request.open( method, url );
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {
            callback( request.responseText );
        }
    };
    request.send( payload );
};
function getDetails( itemName, callback ) {
    createRequest( "GET", "getDetails.php?ImageID=" + escape(itemName), callback, null );
};
function displayDetails( detail ) {
    var detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");      
    detailDiv.innerHTML = detail;
};
getDetails( "someItemName", displayDetails );
```

Comment: In checkUsername method (in a posted image below), why couldn't we just leave var usernameRequest variable as it's in first example with var request ? Why does it said it would not be possible to use it on callback if it's not global variable? And how come it's not global variable and var request is? I mean why we had to remove var in checkUsername() method?

Comment: Both checkUsername() and getDetails() use the same request object? It's single object being used by both? To avoid this we had to make one of them global variable (like im image that I posted?) ? Thanks a lot

Comment: `Both checkUsername() and getDetails() use the same request object?` No: getDetails() gets called. getDetails creates a local variable `request`. and calls createRequest(). createRequest() creates a global variable `rquest` since there's no var in front of it. THen it returns this global request to getDetails and so the local request becomes a reference to the global request.

Comment: I thought we end up overwriting one request’s data with data from another request, so author decided to move it to globals like to try to separate it...

Comment: That's the irony of this all. Consider the same code, but with the callback as a parameter. Then calling getDetails() twice with different callbacks, will only execute the second callback, since the second call will ovrwrite the global request object, and hence, when the first call returns from the server with the data, it gets swallowed by the browser as if it never existed. Hence we don't use globals for this, so we can run two different requests at the same time. :) So it's this exact structure using globals that makes 'overwriting' request data possible.

Comment: when you said Hence we don't use globals for this hmm? What do you mean acctually..  If request is local, then how would a callback function get access to the request object? The callbacks need request to be global, so they can access the variable and its property values. Anyway thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: The callbacks only need request to be global because they don't take a parameter. The callbacks should not care where the data comes from. I'll add the proper way to do this is a code snippet.

Comment: I've added an example using the same names and functions, but without relying on globals. As you can see, you can create another function, like getItems() or something by calling createRequest() with a different url. Or if you want to do something else with the details as well, call getDetails() with a different callback.

Comment: thanks for help, can you check edit of my question, book says variable in createRequest() method has to be global :o huh ?

Comment: To be honest, I would just throw away the book and look for a modern tutorial. Stuff like try/catch around activeX objects is over 10 years old and not all still applicable to modern JS. The author of the book is just plain wrong. The only reason why request has to be global is because of the way he uses the callbacks. So unless the chapter is about the differences between global and local variables and not about network requests, the author is teaching you bad practices. A callback function does not need access to the request to begin with. It needs access to the data returned by the request.

Comment: I'm gonna burn it now :D

Comment: It probably was a good book in 2006 ;) The author is correct for his own code, but only for his own. It does not mean that there aren't better ways to do callbacks.

Comment: it's written 2009 acctually :P Since I'm beginner I thouht I could catch a lot of stuffs, but this seems to be wrong way, cuz for i.e today I would say request object has to be global and acctually it doesn't need to be global...

Comment: That's an issue with web development these days. It changes so fast that if you pick up a 5 year old text, that will already be deprecated. A good example is that these days, you'd use `request.onload()` instead of `request.onreadystatechange()` and then deal with all the different states yourself. Once you have enough confidence for it, try reading MDN, that's usually the most up-to-date reference to everything JS. They also have a tutorials section that might be usefull. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

you are right, in your first example, function `createRequest` is not using `var`, which mean you are creating a **global variable** `request` when excute `request = new XMLHttpRequest();`.

We should avoid using gobal var in most situation.

```
function createRequest() {
    try {
        // add var so it's not global variable
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (otherMS) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return request;
}

function getDetails(itemName) 
{ 
    var request = createRequest();
    if (request==null) 
    {    alert("Unable to create request");  
        return;  
    } 
    var url= "getDetails.php?ImageID=" +    escape(itemName); 
    request.open("GET",url,true);  

    // create anonymous function to call your callback and pass `request` as local variable
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        displayDetails(request);
    }; 
    request.send(null); 
}

function displayDetails(request) 
{  
    if (request.readyState == 4) 
    {    
        if (request.status == 200) 
        {      
            detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");      
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;    
        }  
    } 
}
```